# MacBook Pro stuck on Apple logo - tried everything.. help

Tags: mojave, startup

Out of the blue my 2014 MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave is not booting.. it keeps freezing on the Apple logo.

I’ve tried the following already:

1. Ran it in recovery mode - ran first aid on the disk, all is well.
2. Verbose mode - ran it, text comes up real quick for a second and then it jumps to the Apple logo and the text disappears.
3. Tried running it in safe mode but it won’t work - just goes to the Apple logo as usual. Tried checking if I have a firmware password - I don’t.
4. Reset the NVRAM and PRAM.
5. Performed a Hardware Test (pressing D during startup) - all is well.

Please help me out here.. I’m really trying to fix this but nothing seems to work. Maybe someone here will have a clue how to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: Try running hardware test: https://support.apple.com/HT201257

Comment: Just did.. all is well.. no issues found.

Comment: Do you have data on MacBook that you wouldn't want to lose?

Comment: It's possible that you may have a corrupted disk. To isolate, you can try installing macOS via Internet recovery on an external disk and ensure if the rest of the hardware is working fine. Also, you can try booting into a live Ubuntu session using a bootable USB stick.

Comment: @Eden, did you try any of these: https://appletoolbox.com/2016/03/macbook-stuck-apple-logo-wont-boot/

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling macOS (from Recovery mode)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps, but it happens to me sometimes too, or stuck in black screen when it attempts to start in BootCamp. I realized if I take out or unplug some usb cable from the laptop, it would start up normally. I also noticed it happened much less after I disabled a usb flash drive in Device Manager that I don't plug in and use all the time.